# Ajax call happening 2 times in a row?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html

I have a rails application that I am working on that exhibiting behavior I cant understand.  I have an html file:

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I then have a javascript(jquery really) file that I hit when someone clicks on a row in the table.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("tr", "table").click(function(){
    console.log("TEST");
  });
});
```

Everytime I click on a row in the table, the function is called 2 times.  I get 'TEST' in the console twice.  I am new to jquery and rails, so I know that I am missing something simple.  Someone please show me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: 1 time for tr, 1 time for table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's counting the click for both the "tr" and the "table"

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("tr").click(function(){
    console.log("TEST");
  });
});
```

Comment: you got an answer before I was even finished reading the question

Comment: This is not correct. He is using `$(selector, context)` not `$('selector, selector')`; http://jsfiddle.net/Wfqw3/

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It works in the jsFiddle, but not in my code.  I have exactly what is posted in this question in my app and I am still getting the double click thing going on.  Any other ideas?  I am going to vote you up for a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

As the guys stated, it's happening because each tr is inside a table so it's a correct behavior. If you wanna avoid it, I believe that preventing the event propagtion would work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("tr", "table").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("TEST");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

THe click is being fired for the table click and the tr click try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("tr").click(function(){
    console.log("TEST");
  });
});
```

you don't need a click event on table , unless you want to be able to click in the table- but not in a row , that doesn't sound right